# How to create an entity-reference field programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities

I'd like to know how to create an entity-reference field programmatically, and where should I put this script.
Could I call `field_create_instance()` in `hook_form_alter()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could I call `field_create_instance()` in `hook_form_alter()`?

[field_create_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) is normally called in `hook_install()`, or `hook_enable()` from a module, or an installation profile.

You don't call it in `hook_form_alter()`, especially if the hook is altering the node edit form: Fields are attached to bundles (content types), not to single nodes. When a node is created, its content type is already created, and any field that content type requires is created before its nodes are created.
If there is a setting form that allows users to decide which fields to attach to a content type, then `field_create_instance()` is called in its submission callback.

A call to `field_create_instance()` is normally coupled with a call to [field_create_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7). To be sure the field doesn't exist, you should first call [field_info_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7). It returns `NULL` when the field doesn't exists.